# Wake-On-LAN for ASROCK H81M-ITX

Tags: networking, wakeonlan

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 on an ASROCK H81M-ITX motherboard.  I'm pretty sure I have the BIOS configured correctly for wake-on-lan.  I read [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=234588) about what you need to do from the ubuntu side to make WOL work.

But I get this error when trying to enable WOL:

`sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g`

```
Cannot get current wake-on-lan settings: Operation not supported
  not setting wol
```

Here's the ethtool dump for eth0.  (What is the meaning of the wol in the ouptut?)

`$ sudo ethtool eth0`

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                           link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
    Link detected: yes
```

The [manual for the H81M-ITX](http://download.asrock.com/manual/H81M-ITX.pdf) has two configuration settings that refer to waking from a lan:

1. **Boot From Onboard LAN**:  Allow the system to be waked up by the onboard LAN.
2. **PCIE Device Power On**:  Allow the system to be waked up by a PCIE device and enable wake on LAN.

I'm actually using the onboard LAN, but I have both enabled anyway.

When I shutdown, I'm using:

`$sudo shutdown -P now`

After the shutdown, the link light goes off for the LAN connection on both the motherboard, and at the hub where it's connected.  It appears to have no power.  Do I need to shutdown in a different way to preserve power to the ethernet port?

Here are all the BIOS configuration settings that I found that had to do with sleep states (power saving).  These are their current settings which they were preset at the factory:

1. CPU C States Support:  `Auto`
2. Enhanced Halt State (C1E):  `Auto`
3. CPU C3 State Support:  `Auto`
4. CPU C6 State Support:  `Auto`
5. CPU C7 State Support:  `Auto`
6. Package C State Support:  `Disabled`

Each of these 6 configuration items have 3 possible settings:  auto, enabled and disabled.  The last item (which is the only one that's disabled) has a description, "Enable CPU, PCIe, Memory, Graphics C State Suppport for power saving."  Does anything here look amiss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a tech support representative from ASROCK was kind enough to research this and found information about this problem.  Apparently wake-on-lan support was removed from the Ubuntu drivers for the on-board Qualcomm Atheros ethernet due to some related problem.  I don't fully understand the root of the problem, and I'm not too excited about the prospect of trying to patch in older versions of the Atheros drivers to try to recover this functionality that apparently worked in older releases of Ubuntu.  I may try to find a different motherboard that doesn't use an Atheros-based ethernet.

Some references:

- [Any updates on Wake on LAN functionality being restored for Atheros cards?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251603)
- [Qualcomm Atheros AR8171 Wake on LAN issues](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/qualcomm-atheros-ar8171-wake-on-lan-issues-4175491464/)

I have such a bad reputation, I can only post two active links.  I feel so dirty.  :)  Here's another useful reference :

[Bug 61651 - [regression] Wake-on-LAN broken in alx (AR8161)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61651)

Comment: From the bug report, I guess it is a Linux wide issue, not just Ubuntu. If you want to comment on it (which might make it more noticeable), you can [create a account](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/createaccount.cgi) and then comment on it (note that bugzilla confirmation emails can take AGES). Including your kernel and Ubuntu version may also help with any solutions (both here and on the bug report) Also, check @chili555's answer it may help.

Comment: Oh, and you may need to enable it in BIOS, it may not be a driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

Many, but not all ethernet devices support Wake on LAN. Check:

```
sudo ethtool eth0 | grep -i  wake
```

If it is not supported in your device, there is no known method to force it to do what it wasn't ever designed to do.

If WoL is reported as not supported, you might check the BIOS in Chipset Configuration. What is the Deep Sleep option set to? You may need it set to S5 for the NIC to remain active after a shutdown.